# Keycloak, create client programmatically - 403

Tags: jboss, openid-connect, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have created my realm, client in Keycloak. Inside client created role `create-client` with desc `${role_create-client}`. Assigned this role in `Service Account Roles` section.

But I still get 403 when send `POST` to `{realm}/clients`.

Need help in that.

Comment: To whom have you assigned the create client role? To the logged user or the client?

Comment: actually the client

Comment: And you try to create the client on behalf of the user?

Comment: @XtremeBiker I resolved it for myself. so there were lack of privileges for my client to create another client. I resolved it through admin console.

Comment: which kind of client did you create?